# Can't convert from char*[] to char**

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

When I try a test program with just these two lines

```
char array[256];
char** arrayPointer=&array;
```

I get the error

> cannot convert from char*[256] to char**.

Yet if I do this:

```
char array[256];
char* temp=array;
char** arrayPointer=&temp;
```

I get no such complaint.

I figured that it was eclipse acting buggy (which my eclipase is acting funny right now)  but when I tried to do a cast of the `&array` to `char**` for the function I ended up with unusual behavior and my debugger implying that the array isn't being modified as it should.

PS. all of this was written by hand, forgive typos.

Comment: Hint: if you think your compiler is buggy, you're almost certainly wrong.  An array is not a pointer.  An array is **NOT** a pointer.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield but can you explain to the OP why the second example does work?

Comment: @MrLister `&temp` takes the address of `temp`, it does not care about `array` or what ever address temp stores …

Comment: @AdamRosenfield When talking about C++ compilers, if you think your compiler is buggy, it might actually be. I say that from: #1 having found many more compiler bugs in my short experience with C++ than with any other compiler *which I've used longer*; and #2 the number of SO questions regarding actual C++ compiler bugs I see.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes still I'd say that for 99,999/100,0000 compiling errors, the fault sits in front of the monitor …

Comment: Also, most compiler bugs manifest themselves as the *lack* of an error message, or silently doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++, arrays and pointers are **not** the same thing.  Arrays in many cases can implicitly be converted to a pointer, but array types and pointer types are different.

In your case, the variable

```
char array[256];
```

has type `char[256]`.  If you take its address by writing `&array`, you get a pointer to an array of 256 `char`s, which has type `char (*)[256]`.  This is not the same a `char**`.  This is actually a good thing.  If you could do the conversion, what would happen if you did this?

```
char array[256];
char** ptrPtr = &array; // Not legal!
*ptrPtr = new char[256];
```

In this case, the third line would "reassign" `array` to point to a new array of 256 elements.  However, `array` is not a pointer!  This operation is meaningless.

The reason you got a weird debugger error when writing

```
char array[256];
char** ptrPtr = (char**) &array; // Legal, but Bad Times!
*ptrPtr = new char[256];
```

is that the cast you've put in results in undefined behavior.  You're pretending that a pointer to an array of 256 actual `char` objects is really a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.  This is a meaningless cast, so all bets are off when you do it.

On the other hand, if you explicitly introduce a `char*` variable like this:

```
char array[256];
char* ptr = array;
char** ptrPtr = &ptr;
```

Then everything is fine.  In the second line, you create a pointer (actual type `char*`) that points to the first element of `array`.  In the third line, you create a pointer to that new pointer.  If you then write

```
*ptrPtr = new char[137];
```

Then nothing bad happens; you've just changed where `ptr` was pointing, and didn't destroy `array`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, but it still leaves me confused.  My understanding in C is that a character away is just a pointer to the front of the memory location.  Has C++ somehow changed this behavior of C (which seems like a very bad idea)?

Comment: @JesseGood: No, you've been misled.  Array-pointer decay (I hate that term) only happens when it's requested.  That is to say, when you try to assign an array to a pointer.

Comment: In addition, what would be the harm of reassigning the char** so it no longer pointed to my original character array?  I would no longer be able to find a point on the stack where I stored memory, but presumable I meant to do that anyways.  Do C++ arrays carry some additional state that needs to be freed unlike in regular C?

Comment: @dsollen- Neither C nor C++ treat arrays as pointers to the first character of the sequence.  In both C and C++, arrays are contiguous blocks of objects all of one type.  The array can *decay* into a pointer to its first element, but it really isn't a pointer to the first element.  The reason that "reassigning" the array doesn't make sense is that you can't "reassign" one block of elements to be another block of elements.  Does that clarify things a bit?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I stand corrected, no decay happens with `&array` when the address operator is used. Thanks for pointed that out!